# How to lock all methods of class while using one of it?

Tags: java, multithreading

I can not understand how to do this thing in Java:

For example, I have Foo.class:

```
public class Foo{
  public Foo(){}

  public void method1(){
    ...
  }

  public void method2(){
    ...
  }

}
```

I have different threads with their own objects of Foo class:

```
Thread 1: Foo foo1 = new Foo();
Thread 2: Foo foo2 = new Foo();
```

For example Thread 1 calls: `foo1.method1()`
And at the same time Thread 2 calls: `foo2.method2()`

How to prevent Thread 2's call until `foo1.method1()` in Thread 1 is not finished?

Thank you in adnvance!

Comment: @ControlAltDel, simply making all methods `synchronized` will not do _exactly_ what the OP asked:  It will not prevent overlapped calls to two different methods if the calls are for different instances.  There probably is an XY problem here:  The OP has not explained what the real problem is.

Comment: You will need a global lock outside of the class. Then when a method is called, it will lock the lock (or block if lock already locked) and unlock the lock whenever the thread exits. I will write a full answer in around 4 hours if no one else has by then (can't give you full answer now b/c I'm on my phone). Note that my suggestion may not be the best. My suggestion just requires the least amount of change to your existing code.

Comment: [cross site duplicate](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/206732/how-to-make-a-method-synchronized-across-all-instances-of-an-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need something to synchronize on, you could use many things but I'd add a class field (a field shared by all instances - aka a `static` field) and use that. Something like

```
public class Foo{
  static final Object ai = new Object(); // <-- one to rule them all...
  public Foo(){}

  public void method1(){
    synchronized(ai) {
      // ...
    }
  }

  public void method2(){
    synchronized(ai) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, there is a good way to do this using synchronized block.

Synchronized keyword creates the intrinsic lock (Monitor lock) for an object by which the object can be accessed only once at a time by a single thread, hence it cannot be accessed simultaneously by different threads.

```
public class Foo{
  public Foo(){}

  public synchronized void method1(){
    ...
  }

  public synchronized void method2(){
    ...
  }
}
```

The above edit should do the trick. So, while your thread is accessing your method1(), any other thread can not access your method2().

Second way is to create synchronized blocks inside the class

```
public void method1(){
  synchronized(this){
    ...
  }
}
```

This is actually a better way to do any low level synchronization using synchronized block. Thank you.

Comment: This is not what the op is asking for. The `synchronized` keyword will synchronize on the current object. However, he wants to prevent concurrent calls on **different** objects.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a static object like

```
static final Object myLock = new Object();
```

And then synchronizing the bodies (or even better, just the relevant portions) of all the methods on that object like:

```
void method1() {
    synchronized (myLock) {

    }
}

void method2() {
    synchronized (myLock) {

    }
}
```